# Ionic 2 invalid page component: null

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

When in browser's url I typing **localhost:8100/#/login** it is ok, if I add some hash to url like this: **localhost:8100/#/loginsomestring** and press 'Enter' it shows error:

> nav-util.js:23 invalid page component: null

This works fine for devices - I can move through the links, but for browser I am not. I mean the trouble if I manually add something in the hash. According to cordova's rules on device, I can't specify url, but in browser I can. I am trying to develop application that will work on devices and in the browser like an app.
I have this links:

```
const links = [
  { component: LoginPage, name: 'Login', segment: 'login', useAsDefault: true },
  { component: ContactsPage, name: 'Contacts', segment: 'contacts' },
  { component: ChangeContactPage, name: 'NewContact', segment: 'change-contact', defaultHistory: [ContactsPage] },
  { component: ChangeContactPage, name: 'ChangeContact', segment: 'change-contact/:contactId', defaultHistory: [ContactsPage] }
];
```

And then I have this:

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(App, {}, {links})
  ]
```

So here we have

```
**ionic info:**

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: please refine the question

Comment: *"This works fine for devices"* what do you mean by this? What does it do on devices that it doesn't do in the browser?

Comment: @YuvrajPatil I have edited question. If I can add something, tell me, please
And thank you for your attention

Comment: I'm trying a very similar scenario to what you are trying.  It works in Ionic Serve but when I run it in browser, one of my deep links works but two of them do not.  It's been this way since RC4 as well (on final now).